Reading OTP from gmail
I am trying to connect to Gmail using IMAP and read an OTP for authentication purposes. I am using this logic. Still, I am receiving an SSL handshake exception.
javax.mail.MessagingException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate);
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:670)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at com.crato.qa.EmailExtractor.ReadingEmails.check(ReadingEmails.java:43)
    at com.crato.qa.EmailExtractor.ReadingEmails.main(ReadingEmails.java:110)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:162)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:247)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:448)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:548)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:352)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:113)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:111)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:637)
    ... 4 more

I have tried this code.
package com.crato.qa.EmailExtractor;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Flags.Flag;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;

public class ReadingEmails {

    public static void check(String host, String storeType, String user, String password) {
        try {
            // create properties
            
              Properties properties = new Properties();           
              properties.setProperty("mail.imap.host", host);
              properties.put("mail.imap.port", "993");
              properties.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
              properties.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.trust", host);
              properties.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
              properties.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
            //  properties.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
            
            //Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
            Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(properties, null);
            // create the imap store object and connect to the imap server
            Store store = emailSession.getStore("imaps");

            store.connect(host, user, password);

            // create the inbox object and open it
            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

            // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
            Message[] messages = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));
            System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

            for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
                Message message = messages[i];
                message.setFlag(Flag.SEEN, false);
                System.out.println("---------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
                System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
                System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
                System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContentType());
                System.out.println("Date : "+ message.getSentDate());
                //System.out.println("Text: " + message.match());
                System.out.println("Mutlipart text: "+getTextFromMultipartRelatedMessage(message)); 
                break;
            }

            inbox.close(false);
            store.close();

        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    // Helper method to extract text from a "multipart/RELATED" email message
    public static String getTextFromMultipartRelatedMessage(Message message) throws Exception {
        String result = "";
        if (message.isMimeType("multipart/RELATED")) {
            Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
            int count = multipart.getCount();
            System.out.println("Mail Count= "+count);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
                String disposition = bodyPart.getDisposition();
               System.out.println(bodyPart.getContentType());
               
                    // Handle inline content here
                    if (bodyPart.isMimeType("TEXT/PLAIN")) {
                        result = result + "\n" + bodyPart.getContent();
                    } else if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/html")) {
                        result = result + "\n" + bodyPart.getContent();
                    }
                }
            }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {`your text`

        String host = "imap.gmail.com";
        String mailStoreType = "imap";
        String username = "dskarthi85@gmail.com";
        String password = "epzm qffw vpcn tzuw";

        check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);

    }
}



and read an OTP for authentication purposes Please explain. The only use of the term OTP I know is One Time Pad
